# How to iterate array of nested map, then aggregate values of a specific field by collecting it using stream().map();

Tags: java-8, nested, java-stream, linkedhashmap

I want the to collect the values from the array of Linked HashMap Objects with the value of key = "VALUE".

In my code below, I manually iterated each object of `arrayOfObjects` using stream.map() then get the value of "VALUE" fields. Then every object of `arrayOfObjects` has a child which is an array of objects also, I also collected the value of "VALUE" fields using stream.map() individually.

```java
        // Object 1
        HashMap<String, Object> outerObject1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        outerObject1.put("VALUE", "val1");
        // Child 1 of Object 1
        HashMap<String, Object> inner1Child1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        inner1Child1.put("VALUE", "val1Child1");
        // Child 2 of Object 1
        HashMap<String, Object> inner1Child2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        inner1Child2.put("VALUE", "val1Child2");
        // Child 3 of Object 1
        HashMap<String, Object> inner1Child3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        inner1Child3.put("VALUE", "DUPLICATE");

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> childrenOfOuterObject1 = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(inner1Child1, inner1Child2, inner1Child3));
        outerObject1.put("CHILD", childrenOfOuterObject1);

        // Object 2
        HashMap<String, Object> outerObject2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        outerObject2.put("VALUE", "val2");
        // Child 1 of Object 2
        HashMap<String, Object> inner2Child1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        inner2Child1.put("VALUE", "val2Child1");
        // Child 2 of Object 2
        HashMap<String, Object> inner2Child2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        inner2Child2.put("VALUE", "val2Child2");
        // Child 3 of Object 2
        HashMap<String, Object> inner2Child3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        inner2Child3.put("VALUE", "DUPLICATE");

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> childrenOfOuterObject2 = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(inner2Child1, inner2Child2, inner2Child3));
        outerObject2.put("CHILD", childrenOfOuterObject2);

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayOfObjects = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(outerObject1, outerObject2));

        List<String> outerValues = arrayOfObjects.stream().map(obj -> (String) obj.get("VALUE")).collect(
                Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(outerValues);

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> innerChildren1 = (List<HashMap<String, Object>>)outerObject1.get("CHILD");
        List<String> innerValues1 = innerChildren1.stream().map(obj -> (String) obj.get("VALUE")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(innerValues1);

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> innerChildren2 = (List<HashMap<String, Object>>)outerObject2.get("CHILD");
        List<String> innerValues2 = innerChildren2.stream().map(obj -> (String) obj.get("VALUE")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(innerValues2);

        Set<String> aggregatedValues = new HashSet<>(outerValues);
        aggregatedValues.addAll(innerValues1);
        aggregatedValues.addAll(innerValues2);

        System.out.println(aggregatedValues);
```

My data is similar to the structure below:

```
[
    {
        "VALUE": "val1",
        "CHILD": [
            {
                "VALUE": "val1Child1"
            },
            {
                "VALUE": "val1Child2"
            },
            {
                "VALUE": "DUPLICATE"
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        "VALUE": "val2",
        "CHILD": [
            {
                "VALUE": "val2Child1"
            },
            {
                "VALUE": "val2Child2"
            },
            {
                "VALUE": "DUPLICATE"
            }
        ]

    }
]
```

I want my output data to be like below with out iterating using nested **LOOP**:

```
[DUPLICATE, val2, val1, val2Child1, val2Child2, val1Child1, val1Child2]
```

Comment: I ended up using this

```
  AtomicReference<Set<String>> aggregatedValues2 = new AtomicReference<>(new HashSet<>());
  arrayOfObjects.forEach(stringObjectHashMap -> {
   String value = (String) stringObjectHashMap.get("VALUE");
   aggregatedValues2.get().add(value);
   List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> children = (List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>) stringObjectHashMap.get(
     "CHILD");
   aggregatedValues2.get().addAll(
     children.stream().map(obj -> (String) obj.get("VALUE")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  });
  System.out.println(aggregatedValues2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using a complex Type as you do, `HashMap<String, Object>` where Object is a List, is not a good choice, for that I would suggest to use OOP to solve your problem, so create a class like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String value;
    private List<MyObject> child;

    public MyObject(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MyObject(String value, List<MyObject> child) {
        this.value = value;
        this.child = child;
    }
    // Getters and setters
}
```

Second, store your data like this for example:

```
List<MyObject> parents = Arrays.asList(
        new MyObject("val1", Arrays.asList(
                new MyObject("val1Child1"),
                new MyObject("val1Child2"),
                new MyObject("DUPLICATE")
        )),
        new MyObject("val2", Arrays.asList(
                new MyObject("val2Child1"),
                new MyObject("val2Child2"),
                new MyObject("DUPLICATE")
        ))
);
```

and finally, you can get the values like this:

```
Set<String> result = parents.stream()
        .flatMap(p -> {
            Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();
            values.add(p.getValue());
            values.addAll(p.getChild().stream()
                    .map(MyObject::getValue)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
            return values.stream();
        }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

and output are:

```
[DUPLICATE, val2, val1, val2Child1, val2Child2, val1Child1, val1Child2]
```

Comment: Hi @YCF_L! Thank you for your response. OOP is a good solution for this. However, the technology we are using is dealing with JSON data. We are using APIs only to query data from database (MongoDB | NoSQL DB). It returns Objects with a class that inherits from HashMap<String, Object> . The data is very dynamic containing different fields.

 Ex: Obj1_1 has field "CHILD", it could be an array, object or literals. 

So creating a Class for this is not sufficient since its data model is not fixed.

Comment: @GreenMachineDisposer, I'm sure that you can use OOP to deserialize your json, It will be very complicayed if you continue in this way, to use Map inside Map inside Map..., take a break and look to a solution to solve json problem first

Comment: @GreenMachineDisposer take a look at this http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Indeed, there is really a need of deserialization of our model.